# get JSONObject inside JSONObject by Retrofit2 POST request

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making android application with Kotlin which needs network communication.

I'm continueously failing to retrieve `JSONObject` inside `JSONObject` with `Retrofit2` response.

First I made a Class `JsonObjBase` to get a response.body() from `@POST` request.

#### JsonObjBase

```
data class JsonObjBase (
    @SerializedName("ResultCode") val resultCode : Int,
    @SerializedName("ResultValue") val resultValue : String,
    @SerializedName("ResultMessage") val resultMessage : String,
    @SerializedName("Data") val data : JSONObject
)
```

And an `Inteface` for retrofit.

```
interface APICall {

    @POST("/api/Login")
    fun startLogin(@Body jsonObj: Operator) : Call<JsonObjBase>

    companion object {
        fun create() : ApiInterface {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(StaticValue.baseUrl)
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a retrofit request I made in Activity.

#### Activity

```
val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create().startLogin(opInfo)
apiInterface.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObjBase> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObjBase>, response: Response<JsonObjBase>?) {
        if (response?.body() != null) {
            // TODO
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObjBase>, t: Throwable) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
```

int and String values are received normally, however, I could not retrieve `"Data"` (which is in form of `JSONObject` as I wanted to.

I only got empty JSONObject Data,

`{ "ResultCode": 1, "ResultValue": null, "ResultMessage": null, "Data": {} }`

How can I successfully retrieve JSONObject inside the response JSONObject?

Comment: Could you add some code for `JSONObject `? Maybe you're mission annotations on that one?

Comment: Pls use ROBO pOJO class generator for generating data classes from your api respopnse. Its an android studio plugin which helps you to prevent this kind of problems.  I used use it with gson.

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag Thanks for help, I did not expect that ROBOPOJO would make `Data` data class for me and it really helped a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gunesh Shanbhag I used ROBO POJO generator first.

Here are two data classes it made.

in `ApiResult`, `Data` had multiple options throughout my app, so I made it `Any` to get JSONObject, JSONArray, String, etc.

### ApiResult

```kotlin
data class ApiResult(

    @field:SerializedName("Data")
    val data: Any? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("ResultValue")
    val resultValue: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("ResultMessage")
    val resultMessage: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("ResultCode")
    val resultCode: Int? = null
)
```

### ResponseData

```kotlin
data class ResponseData(

    @field:SerializedName("UserName")
    val userName: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("Enabled")
    val enabled: Int? = null,

    ...
)
```

In Activity, as `Data` is `Any`, I had a conversion process:

### Activity

```kotlin
// for Class Operator
val type = object : TypeToken<Operator>(){}.type
val g = Gson()
val result = g.tojson(response.body()!!.data)
val resultOp = Operator(JSONObject(result))

// for String
val g = Gson()
val result = g.toJson(response.body()!!.data)
val resultStr = result.toString()
```

Comment: I am glad that my suggestion helped you. P.S. For some reason my name tag in your answer is unreachable.